# NHibernate Query List

Tags: nhibernate, hibernate

I have the following code which works fine.
However, I only want to return rows where eventID = 5;
Where can I add criteria to this query?

```
tx = session.BeginTransaction();

        List<Catergory> Catergories;

        using (tx)
        {
            Catergories = (List<Catergory>)session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Catergory)).AddOrder(Order.Asc("catergoryType")).List<Catergory>();

            tx.Commit();
        }

        return Catergories;
```

Any help much appreciated.

---

Tried this but keep getting the following fault;

```
Catergories = (List<Catergory>)session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Catergory)).Add(Expression.Eq("calEventID",eventID)).AddOrder(Order.Asc("catergoryType")).List<Catergory>();
```

> "Unable to cast object of type 'NHibernate.Impl.QueryImpl' to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Kanpeki.Domain.Catergory]'."
>
>   message = "faultCode:Server.Processing faultString:'Unable to cast
>   object of type 'NHibernate.Impl.QueryImpl' to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Kanpeki.Domain.Catergory]'.'
>   faultDetail:'null'"`enter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed return type List to IList and it worked fine.